# When using scala in vs-code, using "metals", how do I set working directory?

Tags: scala, visual-studio-code, config, vscode-debugger

The normal way to set the working directory in vscode seems to be to set the "cwd" property in launch.json. Fine, but using "metals", as one does for scala, cwd is evidently a forbidden property.